# Keep same session after registration FOSUserBundle

Tags: session, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I'm developing a Symfony 3 application in which I'm using FOSUserBundle.

I want the current user (UserA) add new user (userB) and keep session value with UserA. FOSUser changes session with last registered user (UserB).

How do I to keep USerA in session after registering userB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
<?php
namespace UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;


class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;
    private $olduser;

    private $token;



    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, TokenStorage $token)
    {
        $this->olduser = $token->getToken()->getUser();
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->token =$token;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationCompleted'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $this->token->getToken()->setUser($this->olduser);
        $response->setTargetUrl($this->router->generate('immobilier_dashboard'));
    }


}
```

any other solution is appreciated .